# .extend() method returning 'None' and not the desired combination of lists I intended it to return

Tags: python, list

I am playing around with some basic python methods.
Right now I am experimenting with the .extend() method. I basically have two lists and want to combine them into one larger list for demonstration purposes.
This works successfully (successfully as in returning the extended list) in the Shell environment, but not when saving the program. When I want to save the program and run it, it returns the value of 'None'. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
listOne=[1,2,3]

listTwo=[4,5,6]

listOneandlistTwo=listOne.extend(listTwo)

print(listOneandlistTwo)
```

Comment: `extend()` modifies a `list` in place rather than returning a new one. Just `print()` the modified `listOne`.

Comment: This is right there in the documentation. `help(list)`, `help(list.extend)`, or looking it up in the online docs would tell you the answer.

Comment: Not returning the list is endlessly a PITA in python.

Answer (score 10):

```
listOneandlistTwo=listOne.extend(listTwo)
```

`extend()` extends the given list but returns `None`*, so you have extended `listOne` with the contents of `listTwo` and assigned `None` to `listOneandListTwo`.

What you want (assuming you want to leave `listOne` and `listTwo` as they are) is this:

```
listOneandlistTwo = listOne + listTwo
```

* This behavior is by design. If `extend()` returned the extended list, would it return a copy that's extended? Or would it return the original list extended? It's another detail to remember, so by returning `None` you are meant to think, "oh, since it's returning `None` it must be extending the list in place, otherwise it'd be useless."

Comment: The reason for the design is a little more complicated. Mutating methods and functions return `None` so you can't forget that they're mutating, and so you can't chain them together and replace your nicely-indented vertical flow with a horizontal mess of long lines with no formatting to guide the reader.

Comment: "Can't forget that they're mutating" is a good way to sum up what I was saying, I just tried to make it a little more n00b-friendly.

Comment: Slightly off topic: I always thought that mutators should return ``None``, but in my Barron's book for the AP CompSci (which tests on Java), they always have mutators return the result of the mutation instead of ``null``. Any reason do you think they do so? Perhaps this rule only applies to Python?

Comment: As far as I know, it's just a difference in design philosophy. Java, like many other languages, favors what's called a "fluent" API where you can chain method calls, at the cost of the programmer having to know what mutates and what doesn't. There is nothing in Python stopping you from using a similar design in your own classes if that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: This returning none is just a big pita.  How then to handle e.g. a `reduce` in which you want to flatten a list of lists.. this goes from being a tiny exercise to being a bigger investigation all over SOF and/or python docs (which are not good..) to discover it.

Comment: You might could use `list.__add__` in a `reduce()`.