# PySpark reduceByKey keep failing when the number of keys is small compared to the number of values per key

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following code.

```
x = sc.parallelize([
  (1, [3]),
  (1, [4])
])

y = x.reduceByKey(lambda accum, n: accum.extend(n))
print(y.collect())
```

I expected `y` to be

```
[(1, [3, 4])]
```

however, `y` ends up being

```
[(1, None)]
```

Question 1: Why do I get `None` instead of an array?

To fix the above, I do the following.

```
import itertools

def merge(accum, n):
  arr = [accum, n]
  return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(arr))

x = sc.parallelize([
  (1, [3]),
  (1, [4])
])

y = x.reduceByKey(lambda accum, n: merge(accum, n))
print(y.collect())
```

This time, `y` is `[(1, [3, 4])]`.

Question 2: How come merging (or reducing) with `itertools` work in the second case?

When I apply the `itertools` approach on a very large dataset (millions of records), then I get the following error.

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 13 in stage 108.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   13.3 in stage 108.0 (TID 14305, 15.5.15.31, executor 8): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line
>   480, in main
>       process()   File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 472, in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)   File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 509, in
>   dump_stream
>       write_int(len(bytes), stream)   File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 833, in
>   write_int
>       stream.write(struct.pack("!i", value)) struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647

Question 3: Searching the internet gives me no clue on this error. What does this error mean?

What I want to do is group items in a `PairRDD` by the keys, and then iterate over the values associated with a single key to build a logical object. If I use PySpark's `groupByKey` function, I run into the 2 GB limits of Spark.

Question 4: Any ideas on how to group items by keys and then transform all those items (per key) into something else (without triggering memory limitations)?

On a very large dataset, trying the following gives me `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object`.

```
y = x.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: [a, b])
```

Comment: The `arr1.extend(arr2)` returns `None`. That explains the first question.

Comment: [That won't take you anywhere](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/04_rdd_actions_and_transformations_by_example.md#be-smart-about-groupbykey)

Answer (score 0):

Ans1.
extend() function extends the list but returns None. If you want to add two arrays, you should use '+' operator.

```
x = sc.parallelize([
  (1, [3]),
  (1, [4])
])

y = x.reduceByKey(lambda accum, n: accum+n)
print(y.collect())
```

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042506/extend-method-returning-none-and-not-the-desired-combination-of-lists-i-int).